# Anyone knows about this Namespace 'global.Express' has no member 'Multer' exported.ts(2694)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, multer

Im trying to create an enpoint to send a zip file and this error keeps apearing ERROR in ./apps/api/src/app/ingestion/ingestion.controller.ts:46:35
TS2694: Namespace 'global.Express' has no exported member 'Multer'.

My app is develop in Typescript.

Anyone knows how to solve it?

I tried some solutions that Chatgp gave me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, you have to import in your tsconfig.json this lines

```js
"types": ["node", "Multer"],
```

because Multer wasn't imported in the express environment. Here is the example

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json", 
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc", "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["node", "Multer"],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "es2015"
   },
   "exclude": ["jest.config.ts", "src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.test.ts"],
   "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```